# Need alternative phrases to "calendar week" and "calendar month"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, time

We may be familiar with the terms "calendar month" and "lunar month". The former refers specifically to a month as it begins and ends on the calendar. The latter, by contrast, refers to the span of time between new moons--regardless of the dates of those days on the calendar. Is there a phrase which denotes a month which is simply any period of thirty days?

More importantly (for what I am writing), a "calendar week" is the seven-day period as it appears on the calendar (e.g. in the USA from Sunday through Saturday). Is there another phrase which denotes a week as any seven-day long period? (I was thinking it might be called a "common week", but I'm not sure where I got that from.)

Comment: Side note: In much of the world, the calendar week ends on Friday or Sunday.

Comment: @GreenGrassoHolm You're right, I edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: A rolling window of 7 days.

Answer (score 3):

1. You are incorrect in your assertion that a "calendar month" refers specifically to a month as it begins and ends on the calendar. There are, in fact, two definitions of "[calendar month](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/calendar-month)":

> 1. <sub>countable noun</sub> A calendar month is one of the twelve months of the year. *Winners will be selected at the end of each calendar month.*
> 2. <sub>countable noun</sub> A calendar month is the period from a particular date in one month to the same date in the next month, for example from April 4th to May 4th.

<sup>collins dictionary</sup>

The second definition is widely used in employment contracts to specify the length of notice required.

**Is there a phrase which denotes a month which is simply any period of thirty days?** - No. There is no way to accurately describe 30 days except to say "30 days". You can use "about a month", but this is not accurate.

---

2. I've never heard of a "calendar week" before, but a quick bit of research shows agreement with your general concept of it starting and ending on specific days of the week. For example [www.calendar-week.org](http://www.calendar-week.org/) states:

> In Europe the calendar week is a week that begins with Monday and ends with Sunday.

It does seem that "calendar week" doesn't have an equivalent of the second definition that "calendar month" has.

**Is there another phrase which denotes a week as any seven-day long period?** - Yes. We call this a "week". Unfortunately this is not a precise term, as it can be interpreted in other ways too, e.g. a calendar week, or a period of approximately seven days. [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/week) has a good list of the possible meanings of this phrase.

But don't worry, we do have a way in English to specify an exact seven day period that might start on any day: it's "seven days".

Answer (score -1):

The log is available within `a rolling window of 30 days`. Anything older than that will be archived.

I think you can just say `7 days` or `30 days`. If you are in the situation of the sentence above, you could as well use `a rolling window of x days`.